# Receiving error when running code in JS console

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a choose your own adventure game in JS, with some HTML and CSS for user interface and design.

When I choose option "Dungeon" Other choices are listed such as "I think I'll take a nap" etc.. but none of these buttons work... I get the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: Direction4 is not defined
Line: 1Uncaught ReferenceError: Direction4 is not defined"

I know its a simple fix, but I can't seem to figure it out...

Here is my code in an external link: https://shrib.com/#Bailee7abrjpg

```
function Direction (Choice) {
  if (Choice == 'left' || Choice == 'right') {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = '<br><br>A giant black spider descends from the ceiling!<br>You look up and it stares at you through bloody red eyes.<br> <br>Do you run for your life or stay?'
    document.getElementById('left1').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('right1').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('escape1').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('result').style.display = 'inline'
    document.getElementById('left2').style.display = 'inline'
    document.getElementById('right2').style.display = 'inline'
    document.getElementById('escape2').style.display = 'inline'
  }

  if (Choice == 'escape') {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = '<br>GAME OVER<br><br>'
    document.getElementById('left1').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('right1').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('escape1').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('tryagain').style.display = 'block'
    document.getElementById('result').style.display = 'inline'
  }
}

function Direction2 (Choice) {
  if (Choice == 'left2') {
    document.getElementById('result2').innerHTML = '<br><br>You run away from the spider and see three rooms. Choose one to enter.<br><br>'
    document.getElementById('left2').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('right2').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('escape2').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('result2').style.display = 'inline'
    document.getElementById('A').style.display = 'inline'
    document.getElementById('B').style.display = 'inline'
    document.getElementById('C').style.display = 'inline'
  }

  if (Choice == 'right2') {
    document.getElementById('result2').innerHTML = "<br><br>The spider caught you in its web. You're trapped...<br> <br> GAME OVER <br>"
    document.getElementById('left2').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('right2').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('escape2').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('tryagain').style.display = 'inline'
    document.getElementById('result2').style.display = 'inline'
  }

  if (Choice == 'escape2') {
    document.getElementById('result2').innerHTML = '<br>GAME OVER<br>'
    document.getElementById('left2').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('right2').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('escape2').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('tryagain').style.display = 'inline'
    document.getElementById('result2').style.display = 'inline'
  }
}

function Direction3 (Choice) {
  if (Choice == 'A') {
    document.getElementById('result3').innerHTML = "<br><br>You enter a dark dungeon. There's weapons hanging on the wall and everything is covered in dust. It seems like no one has been here for a long time. But, there's a candle still lit on the table..."
    document.getElementById('A').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('B').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('C').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('result3').style.display = 'inline'
    document.getElementById('blue').style.display = 'inline'
    document.getElementById('red').style.display = 'inline'
    document.getElementById('yellow').style.display = 'inline'
    document.getElementById('green').style.display = 'inline'
    document.getElementById('pink').style.display = 'inline'
  }

  if (Choice == 'B') {
    document.getElementById('result3').innerHTML = '<br>You approach a dark oak chest. The lock is broke and you open it up. Brilliant golden light beams up to brighten the room. There are treasures of every kind in the chest. Oh no! A dragon! You died. GAME OVER<br>'
    document.getElementById('A').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('B').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('C').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('tryagain').style.display = 'inline'
    document.getElementById('result3').style.display = 'inline'
  }

  if (Choice == 'C') {
    document.getElementById('result3').innerHTML = "<br>An enormous dragon breathing fire into the air! It's chained to the wall, but it looks like it wants to break free! It has broken free! And its breathing fire down onto everything! You've burned alive. GAME OVER <br>"
    document.getElementById('A').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('B').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('C').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('tryagain').style.display = 'inline'
    document.getElementById('result3').style.display = 'inline'
  }
}

function Direction5 (Choice) {
  if (Choice == 'red2') {
    document.getElementById('result5').innerHTML = '<br>Choice 2'
    document.getElementById('result5').style.display = 'inline'
    document.getElementById('blue2').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('red2').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('yellow2').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('pink2').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('green2').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('yes').style.display = 'inline'
    document.getElementById('no').style.display = 'inline'
  }

  if (Choice == 'blue2' || Choice == 'yellow2' || Choice == 'pink2' || Choice == 'green2') {
    document.getElementById('result5').innerHTML = "<br><br>I see the exit! I'm free!"
    document.getElementById('result5').style.display = 'inline'
    document.getElementById('blue2').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('red2').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('yellow2').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('pink2').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('green2').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('tryagain').style.display = 'inline'
  }
}

function Direction6 (Choice) {
  if (Choice == 'yes') {
    document.getElementById('result6').innerHTML = '<br><br>Yes Option<br>'
    document.getElementById('yes').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('no').style.display = 'none'
  }

  if (Choice == 'no') {
    document.getElementById('result6').innerHTML = '<br><br>No Option'
    document.getElementById('yes').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('no').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('tryagain').style.display = 'inline'
  }
}

function TryAgain () {
  Direction()
  document.getElementById('result3').style.display = 'none'
  document.getElementById('result4').style.display = 'none'
  document.getElementById('result5').style.display = 'none'
  document.getElementById('result6').style.display = 'none'
  document.getElementById('left1').style.display = 'inline'
  document.getElementById('right1').style.display = 'inline'
  document.getElementById('escape1').style.display = 'inline'
  document.getElementById('left2').style.display = 'none'
  document.getElementById('right2').style.display = 'none'
  document.getElementById('escape2').style.display = 'none'
  document.getElementById('result').style.display = 'none'
  document.getElementById('result2').style.display = 'none'
  document.getElementById('tryagain').style.display = 'none'
}
```

Comment: can you put the code here in post please , problem in link !

Comment: as per error, you do not have Direction4 defined. You have Direction1, Direction2, Direction3, Direction5, you skipped 4.

Comment: Hey Someone Special. I noticed that and defined Direction4, but it didn't seem to fix the error! It created a new error. So I removed Direction4 again as it didn't seem to solve the issue for some reason. Perhaps I didn't create Direction4 correctly when I tried to implement the fix

Comment: ok so i fixed the error in the original post by adding direction 4 like you suggested. Now I am not receiving an error but when I press the button in the dungeon nothing happens

Comment: You can wrap your code in two sets of triple backticks (```) to get it posted correctly formatted.

Comment: \`\`\`<put your code here>\`\`\` like this

Comment: Thanks for the help guys/gals! I have many more questions about this game... I have fixed some errors but have new ones.. They are all simple solutions I know, but I am new to all of this and missing some glaringly obvious fixes. No better way to learn than get down in the midst of the code I suppose!